# ActiveMQ - STOMP subscribe with selector fails

Tags: header, activemq-classic, stomp, sockjs

Client side setup to implement selector on a STOMP subscribe.

```
var headers = {hello: 'worldtest'};
console.log(event.get('header').data.eventType);
var connectCallback = function(frame) {
stompClient.subscribe("/topic/receipt", function(frame){console.log(frame);}, headers);
stompClient.send("/app/" + url.join('/'), {"content-type": "text/plain"}, message);
};
```

The subscribe returns a message logged to the console of the frame like:

```
body: ""<message>test</message>""
command: "MESSAGE"
headers: Object
content-length: "343"
content-type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
destination: "/topic/receipt"
hello: "world"
message-id: "4hw8wlab-1"
subscription: "sub-0"
```

Shouldn't the message have been filtered out due to the selector?  Syntax of my selector?

Changing the syntax to the below did not work either.  In this case, no message was returned at all.

```
var headers = {'selector': "hello = 'world'"};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which STOMP client library are you using? Why are you subscribing in the callback method? Please read the documentation of the subscribe method since it seems like you're not giving the selector properly.

Answer (score -1):

I can post my way to send selector inside header .. look:

```
Headers:{
    "activemq.advisory" = true;
    "activemq.prefetchSize" = 1;
    selector = "switch = 'green'";
}
```

I'm using STOMP and Objective-C...

I hope that helps...

Comment: this doesnt give us the correct answer. I am trying to do the same, var headers = {'selector': "hello = 'world'"};, though I am not able to get it working